# UIImagePickerController slow when there is an active AVSession

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I have a `UIImagePickerController` that can be used for uploading profile images in my social networking application.

It works fine when it is used alone, i.e. no other camera interfering.

In another view, I am using `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to embed the camera view inside the view. Here users can upload various photos that they have captured.

This also works fine when it is used alone, i.e. no other camera interfering.

(**This is a Tab-Bar Application**)

Whenever the `AVCapturePreviewLayer` is active, and I enter the view with the `UIImagePickerController`, the imagePicker takes a very long time to load, and sometimes it just freezes.

This is how I initialise the `AVSession/AVCapturePreviewLayer`:

```
self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;

[self.captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:self.captureVideoPreviewLayer];


AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}else
    [self.session addInput:input];


self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[self.session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
```

This is how i initialise the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

- Why does the `UIImagePickerController` take forever to load when the previewLayer is active in another view?
- How can I reduce the loading time for the `UIImagePickerController`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. It seems like calling:

```
[AVSession stopRunning];
```

in `viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

fixes this issue for me.